# How search multiple keywords in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

I`m trying to implement full-text search in Strapi like `keyword1 OR keyword2 OR keyword3`.

I don`t find any sources about that, besides `.search({ _q : 'keyword' })`, but it still searches only one word.

Any ideas?